# javascript objects syntax

Tags: javascript, canvas

im trying to learn how to use javascript objects, and got some issue here.

```
var playerImg = new Image();
    playerImg.src = 'player_stay.png';

var player = {
    posX: 50,
    posY: 50,
    draw: function(){
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.posX, player.posY);
    }
}
```

It is posible to insert playerImg into player object ?
Something like player.img

EDIT:
I can make it this way

```
var player = {
    posX: 50,
    posY: 50,
    draw: function(){
        playerImg = new Image();
        playerImg.src = 'player_stay.png';
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.posX, player.posY);
    }
}
```

But i think it will create new Image(); all the time when i use player.draw(); 
So im asking if there is a better way to do this and have all parametrs inside a player object ?

Comment: Did you try? what happen when you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't want to build the `playerImg` object outside/before of the `player` one.

Well this is one way you could do it, but I wouldn't recommend it because it's not so readable:

```
var player = {
    posX: 50,
    posY: 50,
    draw: function(){
        ctx.drawImage(player.img, player.posX, player.posY);
    },
    img: (function(){
        var playerImg = new Image();
        playerImg.src = 'player_stay.png';
        return playerImg;
    })()
}
```

This construct `(function(){})();` is called a *self-executing/self-invoked anonymous function*, or an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

BTW: this expression is executed only once, when the player object is constructed, so you don't have to worry about repeatedly creating the Image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not:

```
var player = {
    posX: 50,
    posY: 50,
    draw: function(){
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.posX, player.posY);
    },
    playerImage: playerImg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

In general, you can have nested objects or lists, like this:

```
var player = {
    posX: 50,
    posY: 50,
    draw: function(){
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.posX, player.posY);
    },
    playerImage:{
                 src = 'player_stay.png'
                 },
   playerList:['elem1', 'elem2']
}
```

to refer to it in your code you just write (example in case of value assignment)

```
player.playerImage.src='anotherplayer.jpg';
```

this link can be of some help
http://www.json.org/

Comment: Not really what i wanted.
I create image outside the player object,
but i want to have all inside a player object.

Comment: `playerImage` is not a plain javascript object. It is an `Image`